# How to import translation files per page in Vue/Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt3, nuxt-i18n

I'm currently in the process of writing an app which is going to be translated into multiple languages. To manage all these translations I'm using the nuxtjs/i18n module. Currently I'm lazy loading a translation file based on the user selected language. This is the folder structure i'm using

```
./i18Locales
  ./en-US.ts
  ./es-ES.ts
  ./fr-FR.ts
```

And this is the nuxt configuration for the module

./nuxt.config.ts

```
i18n: {
strategy: "prefix_except_default",
detectBrowserLanguage: {
  useCookie: true,
  alwaysRedirect: true,
  cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
  redirectOn: "root",
},
locales: [
  {
    code: "en",
    iso: "en-US",
    name: "English",
    icon: "gb",
    file: "en-US.ts",
  },
  {
    code: "es",
    iso: "es-ES",
    icon: "es",
    name: "Spanish",
    file: "es-ES.ts",
  },
  {
    code: "fr",
    iso: "fr-fr",
    icon: "fr",
    name: "French",
    file: "fr-fr.ts",
  },
],
lazy: true,
defaultLocale: "en",
langDir: "i18Locales",
precompile: {
  strictMessage: false,
},
```

},

This is all working as intended. The only downside to this is that the translation files are started to get quite big. The English one is 80kb.

What I'm trying to achieve is to lazy load the translation file needed per page in order to reduce loading times. Something that would use this kind of structure:

```
./i18Locales
  ./about
    ./en-US.ts
    ./es-ES.ts
    ./fr-FR.ts
  ./home
    ./en-US.ts
    ./es-ES.ts
    ./fr-FR.ts
```

I was wondering if this is even possible with i18n and how would one go by achieving something like this.

Thank you for you time!